# Cannot start my program on Windows Server (Ninject problem, C#, .NET 4)

Tags: c#, ninject, windows-server

I have wrote a little program and now I'm trying to start it on a remote server.
But I get the next error:

```
Description:   Stopped working

Problem signature:   Problem
Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature  01: supervisor.exe
Problem Signature  02: 1.0.0.0
Problem Signature  03: 4d447f89
Problem Signature  04: Ninject
Problem Signature  05: 2.0.0.0
Problem Signature  06: 4b86c56a
Problem Signature  07: 177 
Problem Signature  08: 12
Problem Signature  09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
OS Version: 6.0.6001.2.1.0.1296.17
Locale ID: 1033
```

I use the Ninject library inside my program.
What can I do to make a diagnosis of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
      System.Diagnostic.Trace.WriteLine("Error:" + yourException);
```

with DebugView from sysinternals:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647

You have to identify where to stick the traces (usually you would do it with combination of Try - Catch